# Stored procedure when called in mvc controller returns -1 always

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I invoke my stored procedure for returning the `userid` of a specific user in my database, it always returns -1. What should I do to retrieve `userid` from database using the stored procedure?

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pswd_chck7]
    @pswd NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @username NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [dbo].[Password_Check](@pswd) 
    FROM ureg 
    WHERE ureg.uname = @username 
      AND ureg.pswd = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pswd)
END
```

My controller

```
public ActionResult Login(Login ob)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(con);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = scon;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "pswd_chck7";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pswd", ob.pswd);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", ob.uname);

        scon.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr != null)
        {
            Session["UserID"] = ob.userid.ToString();
            Session["UserName"] = ob.uname.ToString();

            if (Session["UserName"].ToString() == "admin")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "NewRegs", new { v = id });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string message = "Invalid Username or Password";
            ViewBag.errormessage = message;
        }

        scon.Close();
    }

    return View(ob);
}
```

I expect the out to be the details of the person logged in. but it retrieves the whole database

Comment: In order to check if the `SqlDataReader` has any resulting rows, the `!= null` check is **NOT** sufficient - you also need to check `if (dr.HasRows()) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

**For your procedure**

add this parameter

```
@UserId INT OUTPUT
```

and let your query like this

set @UserId= SELECT [dbo].Password_Check 
    FROM ureg 
    WHERE ureg.uname = @username 
      AND ureg.pswd = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pswd)

select @UserId

> you don't have to use the sql data reader for one result, as it is
>   used for data streaming

**Add output parameter to your sql command**

```
SqlParameter userIdParam= new SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int)
   { 
      Direction = ParameterDirection.Output 
   };
       cmd.Parameters.Add(userIdParam);
```

and use this to retrieve your data instead of data reader

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@UserId"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter your procedure as

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pswd_chck7]
@pswd NVARCHAR(MAX),
@username NVARCHAR(50),
@userid int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT [dbo].[Password_Check](@pswd), @userid = userid
FROM ureg 
WHERE ureg.uname = @username 
AND ureg.pswd = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pswd)
END
```

Also add one parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.Int);  
cmd.Parameters["@userid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

And get output parameter value

```
if (rdr.HasRows)
int userid = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["@userid"].Value.ToString());
```